# Build an Web Api Method to be called from Angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am calling an ASP.NET Web API action from Angular:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(Int32 page) {
}
```

Besides page I sometimes need to pass a few more parameters, e.g:

```
String query >> This will have a string like "apartments in London"

Or I could pass the keywords:

String[] keywords >> This will be ["apartments", "London"]

And a few more optional parameters such as:

Int32 area 
Int32 numberOfRooms
Boolean hasGarden
```

Would the following be the best way for the Web Api method?

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(
  Int32 page,
  String queryKeywords,
  Int32? area,
  Int32? numberOfRooms,
  Boolean? hasGarden) {
}
```

I am passing queryKeywords as a String because they can be 1, 2, 3, ...

Would be better to have a String[]?

Are the parameters in my Get action well defined to be called from Angular?

Comment: this is angular core service u just inject it in controller or factory wherever you want and call the method like this
    
    $http.post('url','parameters as object' )
    .success(alert(1))
    .error(alert(2))

Comment: Yes, I know how to call it from Angular. Let me rephrase: Are the parameters in my Get action correct to be called from Angular?

Comment: The `Get` method can have any primitives as parameters, the only thing I think you should take care of is the naming of the params when you send it from angular. If all these parameters are related then I would advise to put them into a class and use that as a parameter. In this case you will have to pass them in the request BODy.